# Fast Fourier Transform of a signal

Tags: signals, fft

I have an excel file which has time and magnitute columns of a signal. The signal is overlap of 4 different signals. It has 100 data points for a second and continues for 10 mins. How can I take Fast Fourier Transform of this signal?

I have searched what Fast Fourier Transform is but I couldn't find any way to implement it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtkqz.png)

Comment: you can add a sample of data for people to understand better the shape of your data

Comment: If your samples are regularly spaced, then `fft(signal)` will give you the Discrete Fourier Transform. What this `fft()` function is called exactly depends on the language you’re writing in. There are tons of questions on here about how to compute a Fourier transform. Please search for `fft` and your language of choice.